# ActiveX button not working when saving .xlsm file with openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, excel, vba, openpyxl, xlsm

I have a .xlsm file containing a macro which is activated with an ActiveX button. When I save the file with openpyxl, and open it again, the ActiveX button has been converted to a picture. The macro is still there, but the button cannot activate the macro. Here follows my code:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_dir, read_only = False, keep_vba=True)
wb.save(file_dir)
```

[ActiveX button before and after .xlsm file is saved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u07rv.png)

How do I keep the functionality of the ActiveX button?

Comment: In the meanwhile, I have repurposed one of the Excel cells as a button. I.e. when I select the specific cell, it triggers my code. The functionality of this "button" does not disappear when the file is saved with openpyxl. Follow the following link to create this "button": https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4354-excel-click-on-cell-to-run-macro.html